# Sql connection not working in release

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I've trouble with my program, everything works in debug mode but when i switch to release i'm getting InvalidOperationException:

[image]

```
_sqlcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.serverAdress + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + Properties.Settings.Default.initialDB + "; User ID=" + Properties.Settings.Default.sqlID + "; Password=" + Properties.Settings.Default.sqlPass + ";" + "Connect Timeout=" + Properties.Settings.Default.timeOut + "; Asynchronous Processing = true;";
```

this is my connection string

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=visondb; User ID=sql; Password=test;Connect Timeout=30; Asynchronous Processing = true;
```

and i try simple to open connection using

```
        try
        {
           // await dbConnAsync(_sqlcon);   
            _sqlcon.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

But in release it's not working and when i'm using exe i just get window "program stop responding".

Where to look for error ?

Comment: why dont you use a connection string in your config?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess (based on the limited info here) would be that one of the values you're pulling from your *release* `Properties.Settings.Default` to generate your connection string is either

- blank (an empty string), or
- not what you expect it to be.

Thus creating an invalid connection string.

You should debug on the line before `_sqlcon.Open();` and make sure the connection string is what you expect it to be when you're in release mode.

Comment: you right but how it's possible that connection strings from debug and release are different first one that works is 
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=visondb; User ID=sql;Connect Timeout=30; Asynchronous Processing = true; 
and the second one 
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=visondb; User ID=sql; Password=test;Connect Timeout=30; Asynchronous Processing = true;

Comment: @user1938408 Which one of those is the debug one, and which is the release?  I'm confused by your comment.

Comment: @user1938408 Are you sure you are showing the whole code here? That first one you have in the comment here is missing things that your code shows are *hard coded* into the string...

Comment: Theres a problem with number of "\" in Data Source, when im using _sqlcon.ConnectionString = @"Data Source="...... in debug and release in visual there is ".\" but when i'm staring exe from catalog i get ".\\" how to repair this ?

Comment: @user1938408 Did you make sure you re-published your exe successfully after adding the "@" directive? Because it sounds like that fixed your problem.

Comment: And again good advice, my settings file was not propagated properly. After removing all files, everything works.

Comment: @user Well I'm glad I could help =)